# Why do I get "Access to the path is denied" when I try to use a MemoryMappedFile class to mmap the contents of /dev/mem?

Tags: c#, intel-fpga

I'm working with a de10 nano Intel SoC. In order to read some registers from the FPGA part from the design with the SO part (Linux angstrom distro) I have to mmap the contents of /dev/mem/. I want to do it with a c# code, with a mono runtime running in my linux.

I'm able to do so with a simple c program (code above), and I've found that with a MemoryMappedFile class (code above) I should be able to do it but I keep receiving a "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied exception". I'm running Linux as root and if I try to mmap another file with the MemoryMappedFile class I have no problem.

Any ideas?

C code:

```
if( ( fd = open( "/dev/mem", ( O_RDWR | O_SYNC ) ) ) == -1 ) {
        printf( "ERROR: could not open \"/dev/mem\"...\n" );
        return( 1 );
    }
    virtual_base = mmap( NULL, HW_REGS_SPAN, ( PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE ), MAP_SHARED, fd, HW_REGS_BASE );

    if( virtual_base == MAP_FAILED ) {
        printf( "ERROR: mmap() failed...\n" );
        close( fd );
        return( 1 );
    }
```

C# code

```
uint HW_REGS_BASE = 0xfc000000;
uint HW_REGS_SPAN = 0x04000000;

   using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile("/dev/mem", FileMode.Open,null, HW_REGS_SPAN,MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWriteExecute))
            {

   using (var puntero = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(HW_REGS_BASE, HW_REGS_SPAN,MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWriteExecute))
                {
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about try chmod,

```
ls -al /dev/mem
```

this command will check your file's access permission.

if only root has permissions, you can give access permission like,

```
chmod 666 /dev/mem ..etc
```

Check this link if want to know chmod.

https://superuser.com/questions/295591/what-is-the-meaning-of-chmod-666

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer.. It didn't solve the problem though... first I got: "crw-r-----    1 root     kmem        1,   1 Mar 30  2017 /dev/mem" so I executed "chmod 666 /dev/mem" but I keep receiving the "access to path is denied" exception when I try to run my program

Comment: @MatiOliva Have you tried to check access permission once again after giving permission? Why don't you check once more.

Comment: Before permissions:      "crw-r-----    1 root     kmem        1,   1 Mar 30  2017 /dev/mem".      After chmod 666 /dev/mem: "crw-rw-rw-    1 root     kmem        1,   1 Mar 30  2017 /dev/mem".       I also tried chmod 777 /dev/mem (should allow all actions for all users): "crwxrwxrwx    1 root     kmem        1,   1 Mar 30  2017 /dev/mem", but nothing seems to solve the problem

Comment: @MatiOliva Is fd value -1? if it was so, check your error code. using perror or open func's errno ..etc

Comment: mm no, the c code (where fd is) runs fine, the problem is when i try to do the same directly in c#. For the moment I'm using two parallel programs (one in c to read the registers and one in c# to execute high level processing), but it's not a very elegant solution...

Comment: @MatiOliva OMG... I can't find what is the problem. Sry :(

Comment: That's OK Retalia!, Thank you very much for you answers anyway!, and I'll let you know if I solve it...